# Does exist any BoltDB Ruby gem binding?

Tags: ruby, go, rubygems, key-value, boltdb

Bolt is an amazing embedded key/value database for Go:

- https://www.progville.com/go/bolt-embedded-db-golang/
- https://github.com/boltdb/bolt

There is any binding (gem) for Ruby language ?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a driver for any language rather than Go because as you say it's embedded e.i. it works like a Go library that just do data manipulation over a file.

What I know for sure there's HTTP or other network protocols wrappers on top of BoltDB, for example: https://github.com/skyec/boltdb-server and even with Raft: https://github.com/hashicorp/raft-boltdb. As you may see it's pretty easy create your own network layer, I've been thinking in do my own.

*Maybe this's not your answer, but it's too big for a comment* :)

Comment: thx Yandry, but I see performances decay, putting boltdb behind an http server (maybe a socket/cpserver...) but I still think possible to wrap blotdb (or any other Go "library") with a Ruby gem using FFI ... isn'it?

Comment: Well, you may rewrite the whole algorithm (Btree) with Ruby and use the same format for the file, but it should be like duplicate the library. Also I guess in theory we can use Cgo and export the library through a .so or .a shared library and use it  with Ruby or C. In fact if you use boltdb in your server you'll lose the stateless condition, that's why I've been thinking in a good network layer.